# 出す as an auxiliary verb

Tags: auxiliaries

It is my understanding that there are two different meanings when 出す is used as an auxiliary verb. One example being 走り出す meaning 'to start to run' and an example of the other being 生み出す meaning to 'give birth' to something or 'to produce' something.

I am struggling to understand how to translate the second instance, as used in 「生み出す」.

Examples:

生み出す Produce (implying making something outwardly...?)
考え出す come up with..? (to let out your thoughts/share your thoughts or ideas?)
作り出す create? (create something new [generally amazing]?)

Is there a general/simply meaning or translation that this 出す implies?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters to your question, but I'm wondering if there is a distinction between the two as to whether the second is a true auxiliary or not. Is it productive in the language, where you can creatively add it to verbs freely? Or does it just exist as a set of established compound verbs. I don't know the answer, or if it matters, but I'm interested in finding out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. My lecturer said it was an auxiliary verb but after some digging I found this video suggesting it is a compound. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENFS1Hys5iM